# strictly finer topologies and bases

Tags: general-topology

i have just a quick question,  if T1 > T2  where T1 is strictly greater than T2  are their respective bases strictly greater?  where T_i  are topologies on a set X .    i dont think so because since T2 is contained in T1 then each basis in T1 is in T2, then by a theorem we know that B2 $\subseteq$ B1.  if B2 $\subset$ B1 then there exists a B $\in$ B1  where B $\notin$ B2,  but this contradicts the earlier statement about containtment of each topology... is this right?  thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is a bit confusing, e.g. "finer" and "greater" (better: "coarser") aren't eben defined for bases and I think you also have it backwards in your explanation.  Also, a topological space can have more than one base.  Finally, if you think what you're saying is wrong, you should be able to provide a counterexample.

I'm assuming you meant to say this: If $T_1$ and $T_2$ are both topologies on the same set $X$ and if $T_1$ is strictly coarser than $T_2$, i.e. $T_1 \subsetneq T_2$, and if $B_i$ is a base for $T_i$ ($i=1,2$), does it follow that $B_1 \subseteq B_2$ or even $B_1 \subsetneq B_2$?

Counterexample: Take $X=\{1,2,3,4\}$, $T_1=\{\{\}, \{2\}, \{1, 2\}, \{2, 3\}, \{1, 2, 3\}, \{1, 2, 3, 4\}\}$ and $T_2={\cal P}(X)$.  Then $T_1$ is strictly coarser than $T_2$.  Now, $B_1=T_1$ is a basis for $T_1$ while $B_2=\{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{4\}\}$ is a basis for $T_2$.  But clearly *not* $B_1 \subseteq B_2$.

Comment: This is not entirely true because there is a lemma that relates finer bases with finer topologies. the basis for T1 can equal $\{ {1}, {2} , {3}, {4} \}$ which is equal to B2.  Every element of T1 , has an element of B1, which I posted, contained in it.

Comment: @Anthony: Maybe you should be a bit more careful with notation so your concern is clear. It's definitely not the case that $\{\{1,2,3,4\}\}$ is a basis for $T_1$.  That basis generates only the trivial topology, and $T_1$ has a strictly finer topology than the trivial one. Neither can $\{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{4\}\}$ be a basis for $T_1$ as that generates the discrete topology, and $T1$ has a strictly coarser topology.

Comment: @Anthony: You seem to be confusing various order relations like coarser/finer as topologies, larger/smaller as sets, and larger/smaller as collections of sets. On top of that you talk about $B_1$ and $B_2$ as if a topological space has only one basis.

Comment: @Anthony: It's true that if $T_1$ is finer than $T_2$, then one can find a basis for $B_1$ and another for $B_2$ such that $B_1 \supset B_2$. This is fine, because a finer topology means having $\textit{more}$ open sets.